Azure functions in Python - "Duplex option is required" error
As part of my data engineering job, I inherited some Azure functions written in Python a while ago. I now have to update them to reflect changed credentials, but keep running into issues.
When deploying, it fires off the below "duplex option is required when sending a body".

I found numerous posts on SO and other sites that recommend adding "duplex": "half" or "duplex true", and it hinting at being related to node.js somehow (which to the best of my knowledge, we do not use). I also stumbled across a SO thread suggesting the error can be caused by a requested token not coming through in time, and making the call asynchronous.
I'm comfortable with C#, but extremely new to Python, so I'm hoping someone could have a look at the code and let me know what/where I could fix this, as so far my attempts did not yield any result.
Our code:
import logging
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func
import time
import io
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

class Office():
    '''
    Uses the Office365 API and accesses the the Growth team sharepoint to extract the content
    of a specific file into a pandas dataframe. The extracted datetime is also added to the dataframe
    for uses in the table.

    For now this class only reads in 1 specific file. 
    For future: Make it so it can take any xlsx file in any sharepoint.
    '''
    def __init__(self, Secret):
        self.status_code = 200
        self.site_url = '<%sharepoint site%>'
        username = '<%service principal GUID%>'
        password = str(Secret)
        #Note Points to specific file now. TODO: Update to take any fname from Json.
        self.relative_url = '<%link to file%>'
        app_principal = {  
            'client_id': username,  
            'client_secret': password,  
            }
        try: # setting up connection
            self.context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url = self.site_url)
            self.context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id = app_principal['client_id'], client_secret = app_principal['client_secret'])  
            self.ctx = ClientContext(self.site_url, self.context_auth)
            self.status_code = 200
        except:
            self.status_code = 403

    def getData(self):
        '''
        Reads the file content in a byte stream format.
        Uses the openpyxl to reformat this to be readeble for pandas.
        '''
        if self.status_code != 200:
            return None, self.status_code
        response = File.open_binary(self.ctx, self.relative_url) # gets a byte steam.
        self.status_code = response.status_code
        if self.status_code != 200:
            return pd.DataFrame({'A' : []}), self.status_code #if error returns empty df.
        
        bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
        bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
        bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start
        df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, engine = 'openpyxl')
        return df, self.status_code

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S") # Get extract time.
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    ClientSecret = req.params.get('Sharepoint-ClientSecret')
    if not ClientSecret:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            ClientSecret = '<None>'
            pass
        else:
            ClientSecret = req_body.get('value')

    if ClientSecret:
        now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S") # Get extract time.
        Of365 = Office(Secret = ClientSecret)
        df, statusCode = Of365.getData()
        # Some error handeling. 
        if statusCode == 403:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Authentication with secret key failed.\nStatus Code {statusCode}.", status_code = statusCode)
        elif statusCode == 404:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"File not found.\nStatus Code {statusCode}.", status_code = statusCode)
        elif statusCode != 200:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Sometihng Failed.\nStatus Code {statusCode}", status_code = statusCode)
        else:
            logging.info(
            'Success in connecting to Sharepoint API and generating {0} object class'.format(Office.__class__.__name__))
            Date_Extracted = [now]*df.shape[0] # Created vector with time.
            df ['Date_Extracted'] = Date_Extracted
            return func.HttpResponse(df.to_json(orient="table"), status_code = 200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Bad Request: did not get any data.",
            status_code=400
        )


Clear Cache and restart Visual Studio code and try to deploy again.

Hello, are these libraries all new version? Or you can try to clear the cache by using the shortcut Ctr+Shift+P to open the command panel and input Python: Clear Cache and Reload Window clear cache. Then try restarting and see if that fixes it.

Thank you so much for the suggestion, but that didn't resolve the issue. I get the same error message, unfortunately.

Is this Python v1 Azure function? Update Visual Studio Code to its latest version.

@PravallikaKV - I'm not even sure how to check the version of the function. I was on 1.90 of VS code, and am downloading the latest version (1.91) now. I also, as per the earlier comment by Jeanneli updated the extensions to the latest version. I'll revert once my installation is complete. Thank you!

@PravallikaKV - Thank you! I have no idea why, but after upgrading to 1.91, the error is gone. The deployment failed, but at least this is progress. If you add your suggestion as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution for my issue.

Please check the answer below.


RequestInit: "Duplex option is required" error

This error may occur due to version incompatibility. To resolve this error, upgrade Visual Studio Code to the latest version as mentioned in the comments.

I have created a Python V1 Azure function using your code and able to deploy the function to Azure function App.
local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}

requirements.txt:
azure-functions
pandas
office365
office365-REST-Python-Client


Created a Python 3.11 Azure function App.
Deployed the function to Azure using Visual Studio Code.


Portal:

